# Android: Custom Toast Notification Inherit Default Toast

Tags: android, android-layout, toast

I have a custom toast notification which has an image and text. The custom toast works fine however I am wondering how do I make my custom toast inherit the default toasts look and feel? I want it to look like the default one with the nice rounded corners and borders.

This is what my custom toast looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:background="#DAAA">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/chatIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_chat"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="@string/unread_message_toast"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:textColor="#FFF"
              />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this in one of my apps. Change a few things around and it should work for you too.

```
Toast ImageToast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
                LinearLayout toastLayout = new LinearLayout(
                        getBaseContext());
                toastLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                ImageView image = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.easter_egg);
                toastLayout.addView(image);
                ImageToast.setView(toastLayout);
                ImageToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                ImageToast.show();
```

Comment: That's great! Very flexible. This can be reused without having to add those layout XML's and managing elements' IDs. Previously I've used the inflator method - not so easy to reuse.
+1

Comment: This appears to not work anymore. Throws an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: This Toast was not created with Toast.makeText()

Answer (score 1):

To get the default background with the nice rounded corners (on lollipop) use:

```
android:background="@android:drawable/toast_frame"
```

or

```
android:background="?android:attr/toastFrameBackground"
```

It will give the Toast background depending on the version of Android, if you want the latest I suggest looking for the **toast_frame.9.png** file under ..sdk\platforms\android-[**latest version**]\data\res\drawable-[**density**]

Text Style:

```
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Toast"
    android:textColor="@android:color/bright_foreground_dark"
    android:shadowColor="#BB000000"
    android:shadowRadius="2.75"
```

Source: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/transient_notification.xml

Comment: Sounded like a great idea but it didn't work. I still get square corners while all the standard Android Toast messages are rounded. I set the Toast layout to layout.setBackground(getDrawable(android.R.drawable.toast_frame));

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<style name="Themename" parent="android:Theme.dialog">
```

from developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

Inflate the view from XML layout and name it as inflated_xml_view.

```
    Toast toastView = new Toast(this);
    toastView.setView(inflated_xml_view);
    toastView.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toastView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
    toastView.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am sorry I haven't got back with you. I will try this tonight and award a winner.